# So why did this Pygame move code work, but not this one?

Tags: python, image, animation, python-2.7, pygame

So I have these two blocks of code, both which are designed to move a beetle NPC in a circle around a screen.

The first one works fine.

```
    ##beetle moving code
if beetle_list[0].rect.x == 400:
    beetle_list[0].speedChange(0,-5)
    beetle_list[0].update()
    beetle_list[0].speedChange(0, 5)
if beetle_list[0].rect.y == 100:
    beetle_list[0].speedChange(5,0)
    beetle_list[0].update()
    beetle_list[0].speedChange(-5,0)
if beetle_list[0].rect.x == 600:
    beetle_list[0].speedChange(0, 5)
    beetle_list[0].update()
    beetle_list[0].speedChange(0, -5)
if beetle_list[0].rect.y == 200:
    beetle_list[0].speedChange(-5,0)
    beetle_list[0].update()
    beetle_list[0].speedChange(5,0)
```

In a nutshell, it checks the location of the beetle on the window, and moves it accordingly.

Now, here is my original code, which DID not work:

```
if beetle_list[0].rect.x == 400 and beetle_list[0].rect.y == 200:
    beetle_list[0].speedChange(0,-5)
    beetle_list[0].update()
    beetle_list[0].speedChange(0, 5)
if beetle_list[0].rect.y == 400 and beetle_list[0].y == 100:
    beetle_list[0].speedChange(5,0)
    beetle_list[0].update()
    beetle_list[0].speedChange(-5,0)
if beetle_list[0].rect.x == 600 and beetle_list[0].y == 100:
    beetle_list[0].speedChange(0, 5)
    beetle_list[0].update()
    beetle_list[0].speedChange(0, -5)
if beetle_list[0].rect.x == 600 and beetle_list[0].y == 200:
    beetle_list[0].speedChange(-5,0)
    beetle_list[0].update()
    beetle_list[0].speedChange(5,0)
```

The difference between the two is that the latter checks the y coordinates as well.  But the beetle would never move.  Why is that?

Here is the speedChange and update def in the Beetle Classes for reference:

```
def speedChange(self,x,y):
    self.x_speed += x
    self.y_speed += y

def update(self):
    self.rect.x += self.x_speed
    self.rect.y += self.y_speed
```

Note that x_speed and y_speed are int variables in the Beetle class that determine the speed in a set direction.

Comment: check your `:` in the 1st line of 2nd code. (its a typo perhaps)

Comment: That is a typo.  I commented out the second half of that, when I was testing the code, and that's how I found the solution. 

When I pasted it here, I removed the comment, but forgot about that.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Second `if` in the second snippet. Perhaps you meant `beetlelist[0].x` instead of `beetlelist[0].y`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second version is more restricted - there are only 4 points where Beetle can be moved.

`(400,200), (400,100), (600,200), (600,100)`

In first version there are hundreds of points where Beetle can be moved.

`(400,0)...(400,screen_height)`, `(600,0)...(600,screen_height)` - vertical lines

`(0,100)...(screen_width,100)`, `(0,200)...(screen_width,200)` - horizontal lines

Because Beetle is stoped after 5 pixel so:

- in second version - after first move Beetle isn't in one of 4 points to make another 
  move.
- in first version - Beetle is still on vertical/horizontal line and it can make another move.

Comment: Oh. Duh.  That should have been apparent. Thank you!